# NullPointerException for addView in nested TableLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add `TableRow`(which is inflated from a separate layout) into `TableLayout` but the `addView` is givint `NullPointerException`. The `TableLayout` itself is in `TableRow` - So it's Nested Layout i.e `TableLayout` inside `TableRow`.

This is all happening in **custom listview Adapter** that extends **BaseAdapter**.

I'm getting NULLPointerException on this line: `trackEventstable.addView(tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable)`

I have tried many different things but unfortunately getting same NPE error each time. And when i check inflated layout for `null`, it doesn't give null.

(Layout files code also given at the end incase you need to view that)

Here is complete code for `getView` method:

```
public View getView(int arg0, View vi, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ScheduleItemRecord y = scheduleItemsGeneralList.get(arg0);

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_session, null);

        if(vi==null ){
            Log.i("error", "null");
        }

        TextView sessionTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.sessionTitle);

        int indexOfSession = y.getIndex();

        SessionScheduleItem tempSession = sessionsRecordList.get(indexOfSession);

        sessionTitle.setText(tempSession.getTitle());

        TextView sessionSubtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.sessionSubtitle);
        sessionSubtitle.setText(tempSession.getSubtitle() );

        TrackScheduleItem[] tempSessionTracks = tempSession.getTracksInSession();

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.sessionTracksTable);

        Log.i("GCA-A-Schedule", "Session Tracks Count: " + tempSessionTracks.length);

        //add tracks to table
        for(int i=0; i<tempSessionTracks.length; i++) {

            Log.i("GCA-A-Schedule", "in outer Loop no: " + i);

            TableRow tempRow = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_track_table_row, null);
            ((TextView)tempRow.findViewById(R.id.session_track_name)).setText(tempSessionTracks[i].getTitle());
            ((TextView)tempRow.findViewById(R.id.session_track_chair)).setText("Chaired by: " + tempSessionTracks[i].getChair());

            //here add events of respective track in another table
            EventScheduleItem[] eventsInCurrentTrack = tempSessionTracks[i].getEventsInTrack();

            TableLayout trackEventstable = (TableLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.session_track_events_table);

            Log.i("GCA-A-Schedule", "Track Events Count: " + eventsInCurrentTrack.length);

            //From now PROBLEM AREA STARTS as I add another TableRow into the tracEventstable
      //---------------------------------------------------------------

            for(int j=0; j<eventsInCurrentTrack.length; j++) {
                Log.i("GCA-A-Schedule", "in loop: " + j);
                //adding each event into a this table
                TableRow tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.track_events_table_row, null);
                if(tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable == null){
                    Log.i("GCA-Schedule", "NULL SCENE");
                }
                ((TextView)tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable.findViewById(R.id.track_event_start)).setText(eventsInCurrentTrack[j].getStart());
                Log.i("GCA-A-Schedule", "Event title here: " + eventsInCurrentTrack[j].getTitle());
                ((TextView)tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable.findViewById(R.id.track_Event_end)).setText(eventsInCurrentTrack[j].getEnd());
                ((TextView)tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable.findViewById(R.id.track_event_title)).setText(eventsInCurrentTrack[j].getTitle());
                ((TextView)tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable.findViewById(R.id.track_event_location)).setText(eventsInCurrentTrack[j].getLocation());

                //Adding the event row to Tracks

                trackEventstable.addView(tempEventRowForTrackEventsTable);
                ^^^ Here i get NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

                trackEventstable.requestLayout();
            }

            //adding the final track row
            table.addView(tempRow);
        }
        table.requestLayout();

        return vi;

        }
```

> **I have been stuck over this problem for past few hours. Kindly help me with this. I'll be grateful, Thanks in advance**

---

**schedule_list_session.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="15dip" 
android:background="#FCFFB7" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/schedule_session_header_block"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/yellow_background_pattern"
>

<!-- Title of Session -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sessionTitle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#0099CC"
    android:text="123123123123123"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<!--  Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sessionSubtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/sessionTracksTable"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/schedule_session_header_block"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TableLayout>
```

---

**session_track_table_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#C4FFB7"  >

 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/schedule_tracks_header_block"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/green_background_pattern" >

<!-- Time -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/session_track_name"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#0099CC"
    android:text="123123123123123"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:typeface="sans" />

<!--  Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/session_track_chair"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/trackTitle"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/session_track_events_table"
    android:paddingLeft="35dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/schedule_tracks_header_block"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TableLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/session_track_events_table"
    android:background="#FCFFB7" />
```

---

**track_events_table_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/track_event_row_linearLayout_block"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/block_time_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background_pattern"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/track_event_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6sp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/track_Event_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#3A2F0B"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_item_middle_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B7F1FF"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/track_event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="6sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/track_event_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this does not compile. the track_events_table_row.xml is malformed.

Comment: I am not getting any xml error for this. Infact on another place where i am using the same layout (other than this tableLayout) this is working without problem.

Comment: there is no `session_track_events_table` in `vi`, which is inflated from `schedule_list_session.xml`. hence.

Comment: ok, then your pasted code is not complete. anyway, the issue is trivially that you declare `TableLayout trackEventstable = (TableLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.session_track_events_table);` instead of `TableLayout trackEventstable = (TableLayout) tempRow.findViewById(R.id.session_track_events_table);`

Comment: @njzk2: So should I inflate it from some else ?

Comment: i don't understand. it is pretty clear that `session_track_events_table` is in `tempRow`, and not in `vi`.

Comment: @njzk2: here is complete code over Github:

Comment: there is no need for the complete code, i gave you the answer, i don't get what it is that you don't understand?

Comment: (issue is line 207, replace `vi` by `tempRow`)

Comment: @njzk2 Respect for you Sir :) Can you please put it in answer so i can accept and upvote ?

Answer (score 0):

**You are finding table from wrong xml layout reference.**

**Try to replace this code :**

```
TableLayout trackEventstable = (TableLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.session_track_events_table);
```

**With this code :**

```
TableLayout trackEventstable = (TableLayout)tempRow.findViewById(R.id.session_track_events_table);
```